# Using NOT IN with NOT EQUAL when querying

Tags: mysql, sql, database, querying

I've got a table named "Positions" and I'm trying to get specific information out of. As an example:

```
Position ID           Person

4                     Joe
5                     Mary
4                     Mary
6                     Shawn
4                     Brad
4                     Ken
8                     Ken
```

Note that a Person can have more than one Position ID.

I need to pull out all the names of Persons with a Position Id equal to 4, BUT they also cannot have another Position ID other than 4 as well.

I've tried creating a list of all users who have position ID's other than 4, and then saying I don't want any users from that list. The logic being that this would remove Persons who don't have ID's of 4, as well as users who DO have ID's of 4 but ALSO have Positions ID's other than 4. Note, this is in MySQL and I'm rather new to it, but I'd imagine the SQL logic to follow through.

```
SELECT

Person

FROM

Positions

WHERE Person NOT IN

(
SELECT Person

FROM
Positions

WHERE
Position_ID <> 4
)
```

I would expect results to only show Joe and Brad

I keep getting no returns on my results at all, no matter how simple I make it.

Comment: edit: fixed appearance a moment ago

Answer (score 0):

First, you are doing a SELECT on 'Persons'. You have two columns named Position Id and Person. Start with that

```
SELECT * FROM Positions WHERE person NOT IN (SELECT person WHERE position_id != 4);
```

Comment: That was simply a typo in my post. Still yields a blank.

Comment: What is the subquery returning? (SELECT person WHERE position_id != 4)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use aggregation

```
select person
from positions
group by person
having min(position) = max(position) and  -- all positions are the same
       min(position) = 4;
```

Comment: While I do not understand the logic here, this does appear to fix the problem. Thank you so much!