# Removing duplicates in a SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I've got many tables joined together for a query and the result has several columns. I'm going to focus on two specific columns holding me up, Customers and Position.

I need to bring in data for every customer with a Position of 2, 3, 14, and 15.

Customers can have multiple positions however, and if a customer has a position of both 14 and 15, I need to filter out the latter number

I've tried using the logic from this post:
[Using NOT IN with NOT EQUAL when querying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57084658/using-not-in-with-not-equal-when-querying)

However, when I use this method I get an error saying that Position was not in the group by clause (or the having) for that matter.

```
select Customer, Position
from Customers

where Position in (2, 3, 14, 15)
```

Results I'm getting of course, look like this:

```
Customer    Position

Rebecca     3
Jane        2
Charley     14
Charley     15
Adam        2
Adam        14
Frank       3
Frank       14
Frank       15
Joe         3
Joe         15
```

But I need them to look like this. Basically, I need all the entries when customers have 14, and I don't need the entry for Position 15 when 14 is already present in the list.

```
Customer    Position

Rebecca     3
Jane        2
Charley     14
Adam        2
Adam        14
Frank       2
Frank       14
Joe         3
Joe         15
```

Comment: *I need all the entries when customers have 14, and I don't need the entry for Position 15 when 14 is already present in the list* !!! Do you understand this condition?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And your error message doesn't make sense.  The query has neither a `group by` nor a `having` clause.

Comment: For instance, if I have this:

Frank 14
Frank 15

I only need in my output:

Frank 14


However, if I have just this:

Joe 15

Then I need that single entry.

I don't need the entries for 15 for each customer 'only' if the customer already has a Position of 14. 

Is that not clear?

Comment: This query doesn't have those, no.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  Something like this:

```
select Customer, Position
from (select c.*,
             sum(case when position = 14 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customer) as has_14
      from Customers c
      where Position in (2, 3, 14, 15)
     ) c
where position <> 15 or has_14 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOT EXISTS for the case of the existence of `Position = 14` along with `Position = 15`:

```
select c.Customer, c.Position
from Customers c
where 
  c.Position in (2, 3, 14)
  or (
    c.Position = 15
    and
    not exists (
      select 1 from Customers
      where Customer = c.Customer and Position = 14
    )
  )
```

See the demo.
Results:

```
> Customer | Position
> :------- | -------:
> Rebecca  |        3
> Jane     |        2
> Charley  |       14
> Adam     |        2
> Adam     |       14
> Frank    |        3
> Frank    |       14
> Joe      |        3
> Joe      |       15
```

I guess for `Frank` in the expected results you wrongly have `2` instead of `3`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution does should work for most dialects of SQL, i.e. those that do no t support window functions. Furthermore, it only uses an uncorrelated subquery, which means the subquery is only executed once for the entire query rather than once for each row where Position = 15:

```
select Customer, Position
from Customers
where 
  Position in (2, 3, 14)
  or (
    Position = 15
    and
    Customer not in (
      select Customer from Customers where Position = 14
    )
  );
```